# AttributeError : Can't get attribute 'myfunctionname' on <module '__main__' from '/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn'> : Django Project

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am using a custom module in my Django app, facing issues while deploying in Heroku.

This is the content of my custom module- defs.py:

```
    import numpy as np
    def myfunctionname(x):
            return np.log(x + 1)
```

this file is being called in manage.py as

```
from defspack.defs import myfunctionname
```

procfile :

```
web gunicorn appname.wsgi --log-file -
```

Traceback:

```
2021-07-06T11:28:32.195664+00:00 app[web.1]: obj = unpickler.load()
2021-07-06T11:28:32.195665+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/pickle.py", line 1212, in load
2021-07-06T11:28:32.195665+00:00 app[web.1]: dispatch[key[0]](self)
2021-07-06T11:28:32.195666+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/pickle.py", line 1537, in load_stack_global
2021-07-06T11:28:32.195667+00:00 app[web.1]: self.append(self.find_class(module, name))
2021-07-06T11:28:32.195667+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/pickle.py", line 1581, in find_class
2021-07-06T11:28:32.195668+00:00 app[web.1]: return _getattribute(sys.modules[module], name)[0]
2021-07-06T11:28:32.195668+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/pickle.py", line 331, in _getattribute
2021-07-06T11:28:32.195668+00:00 app[web.1]: raise AttributeError("Can't get attribute {!r} on {!r}"2021-07-06T11:28:32.195669+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'myfunctionname' on <module '__main__' from '/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn'>
```

can anyone help me on this

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64055214/python-flask-app-runs-locally-but-returns-attributeerror-when-hosted-on-heroku#64056687
It works with Flask, you can also try it with Django.

Comment: @ishSparks did you got the solution? as i do have same problem